# Load balanced URL for micro-services

Tags: content-delivery, microservices, sites-9.1

I got a question from Network team if we can assign a domain url to a load balanced micro service URL excluding the service name like http://content.xyz.com/ instead of http://content.xyz.com/content.svc? Wondering if any one used this URL pattern and can suggest if this can create any issue? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you clarify why the network team wants to do such a thing? I know of reasons to do the opposite (that is: ensure that all microservices have a distinct URL path): that allows you to multiplex all microservices on a single load balancer port.

Comment: @RickPannekoek, this is to explore the options to choose one out of various ways to configure load-balancer. Although, we have configured it using http://content.xyz.com/content.svc but would love to hear if we can use http://content.xyz.com/?

Comment: @MukeshKumar, Would you register the http://content.xyz.com/ as part of your discovery service registration as well? In my opinion, the security groups from a n/w perspective would be a lot more complex and chatty. There is no reason why it should not work (unless there is a hard code to check for context somewhere in the SDL jars).

Comment: @Shiva, yes, I do think there should not be any issue until load-balancer able to hit the correct URL of service. We could register the new load balanced URLs to register capabilities. I also think that it should not be a problem until it's hard-coded some where. May be a good one to give it a try.